# failed to load resource: the server response with a status 500 (internal server error)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

i had build a web form with autocomplete method, the program is working fine in IDE. But after i publish the application to IIS, the method is not working. the console show this error `failed to load resouces: server response with a status 500(internal server error) Index2) . Im suspected the jquery code didn't recognize the controller name. 
[image]
CSHTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CardName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Index2",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.CardName, value: item.CardId };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index2(string Prefix)
        {
            List<CardHolderDetails> getCardList = new List<CardHolderDetails>();
            getCardList = _service.getCardList();
            List<CardHolderDetails> ObjList = new List<CardHolderDetails>();
            foreach (var value in getCardList)
            {
                ObjList.Add(new CardHolderDetails { CardId = value.CardId, CardName = value.CardName });

            }

            //Searching records from list using LINQ query
            var CardName= (from N in ObjList
                            where N.CardName.StartsWith(Prefix)
                            select new { N.CardName, N.CardId });
            return Json(CardName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The following code it is working fine during the development, but once publish to IIS it seem the jquery `url` cannot be read. any replacement for `URL` to controller function name?

Comment: 500 Error means that there is some problem with the server code.. You can use fiddler to see the exact response content coming from the server. Also you should use try...cacth in your code to handle the exception and use some logging framework such as log4net or serilog to log the error messages in log files so that you can figure out what error occurred.

Comment: Considering you can't load static content either with the same error, it seems that there's a general problem with the server. Did you add a filter or something?

Comment: @John i didn't add any filtering on server IIS. Is it considering IIS configuration problem? or i should rework my code.

Comment: You need to find out what's causing the 500 response. Since it's doing it for static files, it isn't specifically related to the method you posted above. Try Chetan's suggestions.

Comment: First of all, why looping getCardList list into ObjList? Both seems to be the same and you are still using Linq to select into CardName. The possible problem with the 500 error is with database connection. Check that.

Comment: Thanks all for the advices. will check further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `_service.getCardList()` returns `null` then the `foreach` will throw an exception which you have not handled.

Maybe that is the reason you are getting `(500) internal server error` and not the jquery `url`, as 500 error code suggests that something went wrong in the server code.

As a suggestion, You should use implement `try - catch` and log the exceptions somewhere to be able to resolve such issues.

Comment: Thank you. will check further